# Can't we use plain Ember Objects in place of Ember Mixins?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, ember.js

Basically I couldn't understand the difference between Ember Object and an Ember Mixin.
If Ember.Mixin.create() is itself extended from Ember.Object then why don't we mix objects created by Ember.Object.create() instead of Ember.Mixin.create()?

Why dont we use Ember objects like this

```
let TestObject = Ember.Object.create({
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('list', Ember.A([]));
  }
}); 

let TestComponent = Ember.Component.extend(TestObject, {});
```

Instead of using a Ember mixin like below

```
let TestMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
      init() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        this.set('list', Ember.A([]));
      }
    }); 

let TestComponent = Ember.Component.extend(TestMixin, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

So I don't want to go into the historical aspects of mixins, other than you shouldn't really use them, and specifically your example will lead to many bugs because of the way state is shared between mixins.

In your mixin example would actually share state between different component instances when mutating the list.

Really, your best bet is to pretend that mixins never existed in the first place.

EDIT: Discussion on mixin depreciation https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/issues/534

Comment: I have edited the example so that the state will not be shared. Now do we really need to use mixins or just plain old ember objects. Yes, both will solve the purpose but how to decide which one to use?

Comment: Just don't use mixins and extend from the base class. The current `Mixin` class is headed toward being depreciated, until the language supports it natively.